# null reference when making an intent switching to another activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am modifying the Android TV sample from Android Studio. Originally clicking on a "TV show", it plays the stored URL on the PlaybackVideoFragment in PlaybackActivity. Now I am modifying to let user choose between using the internal mediaPlayer, or calling an intent to show other system video players. After moving the intent call from "OnItemViewClickedListener" to other function call, it gives some kinds of "null reference". I think it is the "context" problem, but trying "this", "activity", "MainActivity.this", the stored "ctx", etc won't work.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    //...

    fun prepareVideo(item: Movie){
            if(item.videoUrl == ""){
                getVideoUrl(item)
            }else{
                MainFragment().play(item)
            }
    }
}
```

MainFragment.kt

```
class MainFragment : BrowseFragment() {
    private inner class ItemViewClickedListener : OnItemViewClickedListener {
        override fun onItemClicked(
            itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder,
            item: Any,
            rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder,
            row: Row
        ) {
            if (item is Movie) {
                MainActivity().prepareVideo(item)
            } else if (item is String) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun play(item: Movie, extra_url: String = ""){
        //should be more lines to do some more things. simplified.

        val intent = Intent(activity, PlaybackActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("item", item)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

May I know how to fix this, so I can switch to "PlaybackActivity"?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your MainFragment attached to your MainActivity? I think what you are doing is creating MainActivity instance in itemclicklistener and then again creating MainFragment instance inside new activity which is not attached to main activity and getting that activity instance in play. I suggest you store context in fragment and call prepareVideo from that context or directly "(activity as MainActivity).prepareVideo". Also use fragment from fragment manager and then call play on that fragment. Please show your code of adding MainFragment to MainActivity

Comment: add this not null (!!) in the activity: `val intent = Intent(activity!!, PlaybackActivity::class.java)`

Comment: Why does the prepare function need to be in the Activity if it's just going to try and run a Fragment function anyway?

Comment: @cricket_007 simply moving the code from activity to fragment, it works. sorry for asking a dumb question. i am trying to run before knowing how to walk now...